# How to enforce architectural rules in a kotlin+gradle project?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, architecture, jdeps

I want to enforce certain architectural rules in my kotlin/gradle project automatically.
An example would be: No calls from model package to xyz package. Or no calls to the ACL layer from packages a, b and c.

Is there a way to enforce these rules automatically on each build/deployment?

Comment: This should be enforced by a module structure, appropriate dependencies between modules and perhaps code review. Maybe you can employ some static analysis tool to help with some of it. But this is beyond scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building tests based on [archunit](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit)